# C# Dictionary With Different Data Types

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am creating a binary file format, and am expressing metadata using a simple key for data system. The data can either be a string, an integer, or a double:

```
byte[] - 0 for string, 1 for integer, 2 for double
byte[] - key length
byte[...] - key string
byte[] - length (for string only, 0 for integer or double)
byte[...] - data
```

I was thinking of using a dictionary to store the data. However, there is more than one type possible for the data. If it is not possible to use a dictionary, then what would be another solution?

Comment: One solution is to use a dictionary. The other solution is not to use the dictionary. Both solutions work.

Comment: Another option can be using a serializer; json,xml,soap,binary etc...

Comment: Yes, but all the constructors I see for a dictionary only allow for one type of data.

Comment: You could use `object`

Comment: @eddie_cat That could work, but then how would I store the data type (I would eventually have to convert the object to a string, integer, or double)